# how to generate a non-source-code file with ksp

Tags: kotlin, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, kotlin-symbol-processing

I want to to use ksp to generate some graalvm reflect config files.
How can I do that? I found the following post: [How to generate android resource (xml) files by using Kotlin KSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907017/how-to-generate-android-resource-xml-files-by-using-kotlin-ksp)

This describes a hacky gradle workaround to include a resource file in a configured dir and merge it with the main source sets resource dir. This is not the mechanism I would wanna use as a user of a lib, as it ties me pretty much to gradle and its clumsy.

When using `createNewFile` on the code generator, the file always ends up in the source code inside of the jar and not in the META-INF dir.

Is there a better way of using ksp natively somehow for creating a resource? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it:

```kotlin
private val generator: CodeGenerator

generator.createNewFileByPath(Dependencies(false), "META-INF/native-image/io.fabric8/kubernetes/resource-config", "json")
```

This will create the json file at the specified resource folder location